# Symfony translation web site and view the list of languages

Tags: php, symfony, twig, translation

Hello I come to because I need a little help,
I want to translate my website into 3 languages: en, fr, es
I translated everything in the translation file but the problem is not how to display the choice of language on the website and also how to display it in the url

in my balise html :

```
<html lang="{{ app.request.locale }}">
```

and my paramters.yaml :

```
parameters:
    locale: fr
```

in my translation file I have 3 files like this :

```
messages.fr.yml
messages.en.yml
messages.es.yml
```

I want to display a URL like this

```
www.mydomaine.com/fr/accueil
www.mydomaine.com/en/home
www.mydomaine.com/es/acogida
```

And how show lists of the links? Towards it is languages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the following solution is tested on symfony 3.4, might be a bit different for symfony 4.* versions.

In your `config.yml` set all the languages site will operate on under parameters option, like this:

```
parameters:
    locale: fr
    locales: [en, fr, es]
```

Again in `config.yml` set the translator fallback locale & paths to your translations:

```
framework:
    translator:
        fallback: "%locale%"
        paths: ['%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/translations']
```

Then define your routes this way (yml definition example):

```
home:
    path:     /{_locale}/home
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Default:home }
```

Then all may access your home page with every locale you provided (answering question how to display language in the url).

```
www.mydomaine.com/fr/home
www.mydomaine.com/en/home
www.mydomaine.com/es/home
```

Now if the question's is also about how to get translated content on your web site page -  You can use different file formats for keeping translations, I will go again with `.yml` as for example. Usually translations are put to files like `messages.en.yml` (as for other languages, create same files with different locale, e.g. `messages.fr.yml`).

Then assuming you have a key `foo` in your translations files, e.g. `foo: bar`, you may display its value in twig using `trans` filter: `{{ 'foo'|trans({}, 'messages')} }}`.

More information you may find in [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html)

Comment: I have to place _locale in all the routes so that's it?